# Print simple numbers on label printer (Brother, Dymo, etc) from C# (.NET)

Tags: c#, printing, label

As part of a project I'm working on, I need to automate a label printer. It will be one of those inexpensive USB printers from Brother or Dymo (open to other suggestions). All it needs to do is print two numbers on one label.

The challenge is that I'm hoping to keep it ultra-simple in C#. It seems like the solution from Brother is antiquated, and the Dymo SDK is a little more complicated than what I would like. Both solutions require the end user to install the full blown application.

Do I have to suck it up and use the low-level COM solution provided by Dymo? Or has someone found a simpler way to print uncomplicated labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the labelmaker as a printer on the computer.

Then, use mail-merge from Excel to Word.

Create a spreadsheet with rows representing labels and columns representing pieces of information on that label.

Use mail-merge in MS Word using the spreadsheet as the data.

Comment: The label printers I know can cut the labels after a specified length. How can you do that with Word?

Comment: Are you saying that those printers show up as a standard printer? If so, that would certainly be a nicer interface to work with. A well known printing system would be better than an obscure API.

Comment: I just checked the manual for one of the Brother models, and yes, it does appear to have a standard print driver. The driver has options for auto-cutting, etc. This may be the ideal way to set this up. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: nikie, If I remember correctly, the label was cut at the end of every page. The custom page size was entered into MS Word.

Answer (score 2):

DYMO now has a very handy framework that can be used to create and print labels using templates or built in XML.

Here is the download:
http://sites.dymo.com/Support/Pages/ProductDetails.aspx?MainTab=1&Tab=1&ProductID=DYMOSDK(DYMO)

Here is the documentation:
http://www.labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/docs/DYMOLabelFrameworkdotNETHelp/html/N_DYMO_Label_Framework.htm